# railstutorial.org chap 4 full_title_helper.rb causes RuntimeError (Circular dependency detected...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org, circular-dependency

I was working my way through Hartl's Ruby on Rail's Tutorial chapter 4 when I ran into a problem. My project loaded just fine in the rails server until I added the full_title_helper.rb file.

I get:

> RuntimeError (Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant FullTitleHelper):
>
> > app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in 'top (required)'
> >
> > app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in 'top (required)'

I tried adding config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock to my development.rb file as per [this suggestion](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/101) but that didn't help.

I tried switching from rails 4.0.2 to 4.0.0; that didn't work.

My full_title_helper.rb is directly from [Hartl's page](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-title_helper)

```
module ApplicationHelper

# Returns the full title with minor modifications depending on the page
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
end
end
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Disregard this question.

As it turns out, this helper is supposed to be "application_helper.rb" not "full_title_helper.rb"

Changing the name of the file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I mis-named the helper file. Thanks to anyone who looked at this question.